# HtmlAgilityPack - removing all nodes in a collection

Tags: c#, html, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to fix this weird nested HTML I get from using `contentEditable`

```
<span lang="">
   <p>line one</p>
   <p>line two</p>
</span>
```

I want to replace each of these `span` nodes with its children

```
<p>line one</p>
<p>line two</p>
```

Here's what I tried.

```
var spans = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name == "span" && x.Attributes["lang"] != null).ToList();
foreach (var span in spans)
{
    foreach (var child in span.ChildNodes)
    {
        var ch = doc.CreateElement(child.Name);
        ch.InnerHtml = child.InnerHtml;
        doc.DocumentNode.InsertBefore(ch, span);
    }            
    span.Remove();
}
```

This throws a `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException` with the following message.

```
Node "<span lang=""></span>" was not found in the collection
```

I understand why this is happening. Editing the document voids my collection of `span` elements. So how do go about doing this?

Also, how do I cope with text which is not contained in a childnode? Suppose I found this element

```
<span lang="">
   <p>line one</p>
   <p>line two</p>
   line three
</span>
```

How do I de-nest that?

**PLEASE NOTE:** This is `HtmlAgilityPack` for `WinRT`, so `SelectSingleNode` and all xpath commands are not available to me

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: to move the childnodes up one level and remove the span element

Comment: Maybe you can try deleting those spans with regex before loading document to htmlagilitypack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for your issue the fix should be to invoke `InsertBefore` from the **parent node**, not the **document root**.

Moreover I think you can directly "**move**" nodes without creating new ones:

```
foreach (var span in spans)
{
    foreach (var child in span.ChildNodes)
    {
        span.ParentNode.InsertBefore(child, span);
    }
    span.Remove();
}
```